# SSH linux server access: 'Permission denied' using MobaXterm. No problems using Putty, tough

Tags: ssh, rhel5

I'm trying to use **MobaXTerm** to log in via SSH into a couple of RHEL5 boxes. I always get **`Permission denied`**.

I'm sure the **typed password is correct** because when I use **PuTTY** rather than MobaXTerm, I log in with no problems.

Any idea?

Best regards

---

**Update 1**

I have downloaded the last stable MobaXTerm portable version (11.1) and deployed in other PC folder -- I can login with no error message.

**Update 2**

I have replaced the old MobaXterm portable version (10.2) with 11.1 version in the same PC folder... `Permission denied` -- I conclude there is something buggy in my configuration files.

Therefore this question is **off topic**

Comment: look at the sshd log file on the server.

Comment: Yes, please have a look at the SSH log file to find out exactly what the error is when using MobaXTerm.

Comment: I have taken a look but find nothing different in session logs.